# One smart object divided on 3 pieces

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

Probably is not a clear title question... But what I want is a one SO (rectangle shape) that is divided on 3 editable pieces. For example: I draw square,circle and triangle in the source container. Then, on my image I want to place those shapes in different places and transform each one independently.

I know it is possible to duplicate smart layer but how to "slice" or crop a part of copied layer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make one smart object and place that smart object on 3 places and mask away the 2 shapes that you want to show there. When editing the smart object, all instances will be updated.

[image]

In my example, the triangle, circle and square are all placed in the smart object (seen within the dotted sqare). The individual shapes placed in the top row are the same smart object with masked out individual shapes.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I thought masking does not work with smart objects...

Answer (score 0):

Masking works.

If you don't want to mask for some reason, simply choose `New Smart Object via Copy` from the **Layer Panel Menu**, then edit the new Smart Object by double-clicking the layer thumbnail.

By using `New Smart Object Via Copy` from the menu, you create a smart object which is *not* linked to the original smart object which means you can edit it as an individual smart object without altering the existing smart object.